# How to set text layout in a custom component in a different angle in Altium?

Tags: components, altium

I'm wondering how to set the text of a parameter in a component in a different angle, so different angles have different layouts when you press spacebar? Like what a standard component does in `Miscellaneous.IntLib`?

This is what I have accomplished so far the text is positioned at the far left always and when I press space it autorotates. Though the position remains in the far left. I want to define the layout to be in the vertical middle position of the component whenever the component is in a vertical position. Like what its done in the native components.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of Altium 14, you can't really create a position for the text on each angle. What you can do instead is to copy the component from `Miscellaneous Devices.IntLib`. Though the copying part is not so straightforward. Here is the following steps to copy a resistor from Altium.

1. Open the file `Miscellanenuos Devices.IntLib`.
2. Click on `Extract Sources`.
3. Double click the file `Miscellaneous Devices.SchLib`.
4. Copy one resistor from `SCH Library` pane.
5. Paste it on your schematic library.